# What does the `i` character in this regex do/mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

I cannot find what the `i` just after the regex here represents.

```
/[^a-z0-9\s]/i
```

Comment: `/` are regex delimiters and `i` is for case insensitive pattern matching

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Ah okay pretty straight forward, therefore would `/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]/` make the same match?

Comment: @scabbyjoe: Yes. EDIT: Err, no - you forgot the `^`. But with it, yes.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (`i`) is the modifier used for case insensitive matching.

Example regex: `/hello/`  (without i) matches only the string `hello`

Whereas the regex `/hello/i` (with i) matches the strings `hello, Hello, HeLLo, etc` without considering case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `ignore case` flag. Please research more about regexs; the flags are easy to find about!

The matches will ignore case:

`/toto/i` will accept `TOTO,toto,ToTo`.

Comment: My apologies, I had just completed http://regexone.com/ and it did not cover flags.

Comment: No problem, it happens. Check cheatsheets on website such as [this one](http://regexr.com/)! :-)

Comment: Forgot to tag you @scabbyjoe